# pygtk GtkTreeIter comparision

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk

I have a ListStore in PyGTK, which has a bunch of rows. There is a background job processing the data represented  by the rows, and when it finishes, it needs to update the row. Of course, to do this, it needs to know *which* row to update, and is thus keeping an iterator to the row around. However, during the background jobs life, the user might remove the row. This is OK — we just replace the stored iterator with "None", and the background job continues along merrily. The problem is that when the row is removed, the iterators don't compare as equal, and nothing gets set to None. In fact, *no two iterators*, AFAIK, compare equal. The problem, in a minimal example, is this:

```
>>> store = gtk.ListStore(int)
>>> store.insert(1)
<GtkTreeIter at 0x1d49600>
>>> print store[0].iter == store[0].iter
False
```

False, yet they're the same iterator! (I'm aware they are different instances, but they represent the same thing, and they define a `__eq__` method.) What am I missing here, and how do I keep track of rows in a ListStore for later updating?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the list store's `.get_path(iter)` method, and compare the resulting paths, instead of comparing the iterators directly.

UPDATE: You can just call `set_value` with the invalid `iter`. `gtk` will give you a warning but will not throw an exception or anything. It probably just checks whether it's a valid iter anyway.

Comment: According to the docs, "This method is slow. Only use it for debugging and/or testing purposes.", so I was hoping to avoid it. (I could do the iterator management in O(1) time... if they compared properly.)

Comment: This approach crossed my mind. It seems to work, however, I can't use this quickly, as I can't build a hash-table index on the path, since it changes whenever the user changes the list, and I'm back to just O(n) searching my data.

Comment: what about the latest update? just call `set_value` anyway =P

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this differently — here's what I've done in a similar situation:

1. The underlying data object represented in each row is an instance of a `GObject`
2. This `GObject` subclass has a bunch of properties
3. When the property changes, it emits the `notify::myproperty` signal

At the same time:

1. My `ListStore` stores these objects, and uses the `gtk.TreeViewColumn.set_cell_data_func()` method to render each column (see note below)
2. For each object/row, my object managing the `TreeView` connects to the `notify::myproperty`
3. The function connected to this `notify::...` signal triggers the `row-changed` signal on the `ListStore`

Some code:

```
def on_myprop_changed(self, iter, prop):
    path = self.model.get_path(iter)
    self.model.row_changed(path ,iter)

def on_thing_processed(self, thingdata):
    # Model is a ListStore
    tree_iter = self.model.append((thingdata,))

    # You might want to connect to many 'notify::...' signals here,
    # or even have your underlying object emit a single signal when
    # anything is updated.
    hid = thingdata.connect_object('notify::myprop',
                                   self.on_myprop_changed,
                                   tree_iter)
    self.hids.add((thingdata, hid))
```

I keep the hids in a list so I can disconnect them when the table is cleared. If you let individual rows get removed, you'll probably need to store them in a map (path -> hid, or object -> hid).

*Note:* You need to remember that `set_cell_data_func` causes the row to re-check its information every time there's a redraw, so the underlying function should just be a lookup function, not an intensive computation. Practically speaking, because of this you could get away with not doing the "connect-to-signal/emit-row-changed" procedure, but personally I feel better knowing that there won't be any edge cases.